# PowerBI DAX Rank basis filtered Measure

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax, rank

I have sales table wherein we have attributes like Store Name, Sales and row level measure of Index Value.
I need to filter the table basis index value (greater than 0.0) and then compute rank in ascending order of Index Values

STORE NAME      |   Sales          | Index Value

A               |   10             |      0.5

B               |   15             |      0.4

C               |   15             |      0

So here, my output should contain rank of stores A,B only(2,1) and not C

PS Note: Index Value is a calculated measure

Answer (score 0):

Based on your sample data,seems like you need the rank order Descending

Use the below

```
IndexRank = RANKX(ALL(Sales),[Index Value]>0.0,,DESC,Dense)
```